# how can i display two columns in listview. that columns data is coming from SQLite database

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

How can i display two columns in listview that columns data is coming from sqlite database?In that columns first column is TextView and another column is EditView.
i have tried below code. But I got the following exception

```
unable to start the activity ComponentInfo:java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

the code is shown below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categorynew);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    getList();
}

public void getList()
{  
    int x = 0;
    cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM detaillist ORDER BY symbol",null);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
        al.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("symbol")));
        al1.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("position")));

        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
    String[] str = new String[al.size()];
    strArray = al.toArray(str);
    String[] str1 = new String[al1.size()];
    strArray1 = al1.toArray(str1);
    lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
} 

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        EditText text2;

    }

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return symbols.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.editcategorylist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
            holder.text2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postion);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(strArray[position]);

        Log.e("text",holder.text.toString());
        holder.text2.setText(strArray1[position]);
        Log.e("text2",holder.text2.toString());   

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is throwing the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

This link here has slightly different implementation but you can use bits of the tutorial and cook something of your own. A starting point if you would. It makes use of a DB and display the results in a tabular form.

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/